# Alternative method for tying bunch of wires

Tags: safety, wiring, protection

I'm making control panels on which some heavy duty PCBs are mounted, with many wires (approx 1 meter long) coming out of it. Wires are  currently tied together using zip ties at every regular distance. It is time consuming, so does anyone have any alternative? Note that I don't want to increase the cost, so I prefer a cheaper alternative if possible.

Comment: sporting goods: hockey tape b/w? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hockey_tape

Comment: if you are doing high quantities you could go for an automated cable tie machine such as http://www.cablecutting.net/Handheld-Nylon-Cable-Tie-Machine-WPM-2502.html. Wouldn't be cheaper unless you factor in the time saved

Comment: @ks0ze great idea, already started looking into it..  Thank you

Comment: In Rancho Bernardo , our Unisys factory for making servers had  dozens of test bays with a 10" dia bundle of fibre optic cables from basement mainframe to all the computer towers (D.U.T.)  Here we used cable troughs in the overhead with bundles dropped to each station which could test many units.  In the old mainframe test days, we had 6 mainframes in a bedroom sized raised floor, halon + Liebert etc with 3/4" cables (~100) with dual port testing to all large HDD cabinets under test. Lots of cable troughing.

Answer (score 6):

I think zipties are quick, easy and flexible - you can take wires out of the bundle at any location.

However, look at DigiKey or other electrical/electronic supplier for "wire management" or "cable management".  Some possible products: expandable tubing, split tubing, nylon spiral wrap.

Comment: There is hook-and-loop (eg. Velcro) split tubing too.

Answer (score 6):

The old-school method of [lacing with cord](http://www.dairiki.org/hammond/cable-lacing-howto/) is still possible, and pretty fast once you get used to it.

[image]

More likely, you might want to invest in a fully automatic cable tie application machine. They are available with vibratory feeders to feed cheap loose cable ties so you don't have to buy special types of ties.

Comment: Yes, automated tie machines is what will help me more...  And I have started lookin into it..  Thanks a lot

Answer (score 5):

Can you use this type of wire harness tubing:

[image]

It can be obtained in many diameters and several colors are available.

This tubing can have electrical tape wrapped around it at points where bending stress would tend to pop the slit of the tubing open.

Note: In the above picture something has been placed in the slit on the far side to hold it open. Normally the slit sits closed up. This tubing is made as a pleated tubing and then slit afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
$28 budget version  or spend up to $1k for power assist and spool feeder

[image]

Comment: I have one of those manual type. Works quite well and at full pull you just twist the tool sideways 90 degrees and it cuts off the tail right by the catch box.

Answer (score 0):

Velcro is cheap. Even cheaper if you use the green ones used for planting gardens. Roll of 50ft for 2 bucks vs the computer kind 7 dollars. Holds then just as good as if t he computer cables were biological.